# Is MainFlux implementation OneM2M compliant?

Tags: onem2m

I was reviewing Etsi's standards on M2M, IoT and came across [this document](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_tr/103500_103599/103535/01.01.01_60/tr_103535v010101p.pdf).

I saw MainFlux mentioned on pages 37 and 38 and I was curious if MainFlux's implementation is OneM2M compliant?

Comment: I have never heard of MainFlux in the context of oneM2M or smartM2M. It looks to me that this a proprietary solution. I guess you will get a definite answer from MainFLux support account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainflux maintainer here.
It is ***not*** OneM2M compliant.